# Override Native Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

Specifically I would like to override the `getElementsByClassName` function that is available in every browser except IE. IE uses a `querySelectorAll` instead.

```
Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName) {
        return this.getElementsByClassName(className);
    } else if(document.querySelectorAll) {
        return this.querySelectorAll(className);
    }
};
```

But when running the code in Firefox, it uses the native function instead. Will this still work as a cross browser solution and use my prototype instead if the getElementsByClassName is not available, or is there a way to override the native function so my code is used everytime? I can name the prototype a similar name, but for ease of readability, id prefer to keep it the same.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a real shim (polyfill) instead? That is: `if(!Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName) { Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function () {...}; }` http://polyfilljs.com/polyfills/getelementsbyclassname.html

Comment: You are confused, *getElementsByClassName* is a [host](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8) method, not a [native](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6) method.

Comment: @MattBall—do not use this method. You can't expect to be able to modify **host** objects or methods in this way (research why Prototype.js dropped it as a strategy). And if attempted, you should at least include thorough feature testing.

Comment: I guess I was a little confused. None the less, I need the function which is why I am attempting a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to add Matt Ball's answer as a true accepted answer to this question. As he mentioned, its best to use a polyfill instead of the way I originally had it set up.

```
if(!Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName) {
    Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
        return this.querySelectorAll(className);
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't a particularly good solution since many browsers don't implement a prototype inhertiance scheme for DOM objects (often the ones that don't have *getElementsByClassName*). It also lacks suitable feature detection, which is essential.

Comment: You should take a second look at how the polyfill actually works. http://polyfilljs.com/js/mylibs/getelementsbyclassname.js

Comment: @RobG Do you have a better solution you wouldn't mind sharing?

Comment: Is how I was originally doing it the best way?

Comment: Write a simple function that provides the same functionality. If you can't do that (it should take less than an hour, including testing and documentation), there are plenty of examples on the web.